# CTreeCtrl HTREEITEM hItem

Tags: mfc, tree

Is it possible to get the Item from the tree based upon the text of the item?

Sat My Item (Hello) is inserted into a tree and say after More N number of insertions I want to get the HTREEITEM hItem  of Hello item.

I do  not want to go to the root and loop as my tree grows very big.

Please help

Comment: Save it and remember it....

Comment: Write yourself a "find" function passing the text of the item.

Comment: Use map and keep storing the text(as key) & HTREEITEM(as value) while inserting and use it.

Comment: So your requirement is, that you want to find an item without looking for it. Sounds like you caught yourself in an unsolvable mess. Have you actually gathered profiling data indicating that a linear search too expensive?